# How to Include System Prompt and Instruction in Vertex AI LLaMA 2-7B Chat Model

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, llama

I'm working with the LLaMA 2-7B chat model deployed on Google Cloud's Vertex AI, and I'm facing a challenge in including a system prompt and user instruction within the model's prompt format.

For local versions, I've been using a formatted prompt structure as follows:

```py
system_prompt = "Your system instruction here"
user_message = "Your user input here"

formatted_prompt = f"""
<s>[INST] <<SYS>>
{ system_prompt }
<</SYS>>

{ user_message } [/INST]
"""
```

However, I'm unsure how to adapt this for use with the deployed model in Vertex AI. Here's the current code snippet I'm using for making predictions:

```py
from google.cloud import aiplatform

PROJECT_ID = "--"
ENDPOINT_ID = "--"
LOCATION = "us-central1"
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "service_account.json"

def endpoint_predict_sample(project: str, location: str, instances: list, endpoint: str):
    aiplatform.init(project=project, location=location)
    endpoint = aiplatform.Endpoint(endpoint)
    prediction = endpoint.predict(instances=instances)
    print(prediction)
    return prediction

instances = [
    {
        "prompt": "Some prompt",
        "max_tokens": 2000
    }
]

response = endpoint_predict_sample(
    project=PROJECT_ID,
    location=LOCATION,
    instances=instances,
    endpoint=ENDPOINT_ID
)
```

My question is, how do I properly integrate the system_prompt and user_message into the instances object for the deployed model? Should the formatted prompt be used directly, or is there a specific way to structure it for Vertex AI?